# Grails: JSON.parse() Error on Linux - Works on Windows - stumped

Tags: java, facebook, json, grails

I'm working on some Facebook OAuth 2.0 code to fix a current plugin. I'm 99 percent completed, but when I deployed my code to Linux it does not work (developed on Windows).

The error I'm getting is:
`Exception Message: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 277 of {"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","code":"AQDZPCNUY2VHnN1R340mArRUggpP1393V9E0VeL-fJbp0VdRBOzR5S5sHQB5ysdhfX8BrPP0u43EVi5OBx5MnrbxROJsuwMrqHmEDRa2pFm-GQ-2_R1blo_uBgOoKFG_Gm0TvtiKhzR1LwV8KNJlAgfCikuzx-zCxDmUz4t6b6xWbvrLPBMYZaLzdy5te3lYGqk","issued_at":1324533514,"user_id":"123144996"} 
Caused by: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 277 of {"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","code":"AQDZPCNUY2VHnN1R340mArRUggpP1393V9E0VeL-fJbp0VdRBOzR5S5sHQB5ysdhfX8BrPP0u43EVi5OBx5MnrbxROJsuwMrqHmEDRa2pFm-GQ-2_R1blo_uBgOoKFG_Gm0TvtiKhzR1LwV8KNJlAgfCikuzx-zCxDmUz4t6b6xWbvrLPBMYZaLzdy5te3lYGqk","issued_at":1324533514,"user_id":"123144996"}`

Right before this error. I was getting the same message without the ending }
As a hack I actually used code like the following:

```
if (!jsonData.trim().endsWith("}")) {
    jsonData = jsonData + "}"
}
```

I'm not sure how this code can work differently on Windows than Linux. Looking for ideas. Not sure if it is encoding? new URL().text? The decodeBase64 code? Thoughts?

```
    String[] signedRequestParts = signedRequest.split('\\.')
    // signedRequest gets deconstructed into a JSON packet
    String jsonData = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(signedRequestParts[1].getBytes()), 'UTF-8')
    // attempt at temporary hack fix    
    if (!jsonData.trim().endsWith("}")) {
        jsonData = jsonData + "}"
    }

    def json = JSON.parse(jsonData) // I get that error on this line
    def fbToken
    if (json.code) {
        def u = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token' +
                '?client_id=' + applicationId + '&client_secret=' + secret +
                '&redirect_uri=' + '&code=' + json.code
        def content = new URL(u).text
        fbToken = content.split("&")[0].split("=")[1];
    }
```

Comment: Secondary, issue being the Base64.decodeBase64 is missing the last character } when it comes back from this call.

Answer (score 0):

*java.lang.String.getBytes()* also takes a charset. Have you tried *getBytes("UTF-8")*?

Comment: Yes, your 'UTF-8' is passed to _new String()_ and not _.getBytes()_.

Comment: I tried using Base64 base64 = new Base64(true); before I decode. And it works on Windows does not work on my Linux servers. I get a Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64(java.lang.Boolean). Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using the apache commons Base64, try using the Grails Base64 codec: _signedRequestParts[1].decodeAsBase64()_